# Improve VBA code to copy a worksheet to a new workbook and save it as CSV file

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA code which copies a worksheet to a new wokrbook and saves the workbook as a CSV file. This code does it job but it take quite a while (~ 10 - 15 minutes) to do all the steps. So, I am asking for the help whether it is possible to optimize these code to run it faster.

Steps which take a while are 1) opening the file 2) copying the data from the worksheet 3) saving a file as it uploads to the sharepoint. The last step is probably the longest one as it uploads ~200 mb to the sharepoint folder

File which is opened is heavy (~250mb) and containt a lot of data, so here I believe nothing cannot be done

For copying innfo I have tried to use

```
closedbook.Sheets("new rates").Range("A:AW").Value2 = newbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value2
```

Instead of

```
closedbook.Sheets("new rates").Range("A:AW").Copy
newbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

But it gave me error "Object required"

If you have any suggestions how to make this code faster, I would really appreciate it. The whole code is below

```
Sub CSVformWorksheet()
Dim year As Variant
Dim filetopen As Variant
Dim diaFile As FileDialog
year = Format(Now(), "yyyy")
Set diaFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With diaFile
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = "https://website.sharepoint.com/sites/folders/Shared Documents/Fodler/AnotherFolder/" & year & "/"
    .Show
    End With
filetopen = diaFile.SelectedItems(1)
    If filetopen <> False Then
    With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .AskToUpdateLinks = False
    .DisplayClipboardWindow = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .EnableAnimations = Flase
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        Set closedbook = Workbooks.Open(filetopen)
        Set newbook = Workbooks.Add
        closedbook.Sheets("new rates").Range("A:AW").Copy
        newbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        newbook.SaveAs Filename:="https://website.sharepoint.com/sites/Folder/Shared Documents/Folder/Another Folder/18/Calculators/2021/Folder/work/Total_RF_CSV.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, Local:=True
        closedbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        newbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .AskToUpdateLinks = True
    .DisplayClipboardWindow = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .EnableAnimations = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With
    ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - Total_RF CSV").Refresh
    MsgBox "File was saved to the folder | Data refreshed", vbInformation
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the data in columns A:AW in a long, wide table with headings and no blank rows and cells at the top?

Comment: i'm thinking you could save some time by setting the copy range to the cells with data, such as with closedbook.Sheets("new rates").Range("A1").CurrentRegion

Comment: Well, this is a long range of data with ~700,000 rows (the number of rows may increase), but it’s not a smart table, just data. The data starts from the second row with headers. There are empty cells in the table, but there are no rows where all the cells would be empty.

Comment: have you considered using PowerQuery instead of the range copy? To use powerquery open NewBook and do Data- Get Data - From File - From Workbook, etc.  That will make a permanent connection between the two workbooks that can be refreshed either manually or by code, bringing the new data in

Comment: If all you are doing is copying to another workbook and saving as CSV, why don't you just open and save as CSV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Export Worksheet to CSV

- Carefully adjust the values (paths) in the constants section since there are possibly some typos (in your post and/or here).
- Since you only need values (`CSV`), the so-called `copying by assignment` is the fastest:

  ```
  dfCell.Resize(srg.Rows.Count, srg.Columns.Count).Value = srg.Value
  ```

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ExportWorksheetToCSV()
    Const ProcName As String = "ExportWorksheetToCSV"
    Const ProcTitle As String = "Export Worksheet to CSV"
    
    ' Source
    Const sYearFormat As String = "YYYY"
    Const sFolderPathLeft As String = "https://website.sharepoint.com/sites/" _
        & "Folder/Shared Documents/" _
        & "Folder/Another Folder/"
    Const sName As String = "New Rates"
    Const sCols As String = "A:AW"
    ' Destination
    Const dFilePath As String = "https://website.sharepoint.com/sites/" _
        & "Folder/Shared Documents/" _
        & "Folder/Another Folder/18/Calculators/2021/" _
        & "Folder/work/Total_RF_CSV.csv"
    Const dFirst As String = "A1"
    ' ThisWorkbook
    Const qName As String = "Query - Total_RF CSV"
 
    Dim MsgString As String
    Dim WasSuccessful As Boolean
    
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Dim sYear As String: sYear = Format(Now, sYearFormat)
    Dim sFolderPath As String: sFolderPath = sFolderPathLeft & sYear & "/"
 
    Dim sFilePath As String
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = sFolderPath
        If .Show Then
            sFilePath = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            MsgBox "Dialog canceled.", vbExclamation, ProcTitle
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks.Open(sFilePath)
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim srg As Range
    With sws.Range(sCols)
        Dim sCell As Range
        Set sCell = .Find("*", xlFormulas, , , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        Set srg = .Resize(sCell.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks.Add
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Worksheets(1)
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range(dFirst)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(srg.Rows.Count, srg.Columns.Count)
    drg.Value = srg.Value
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
    dwb.SaveAs Filename:=dFilePath, FileFormat:=xlCSV, Local:=True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    dwb.Close
    
    swb.Close False
    
    With ThisWorkbook
        .Connections(qName).Refresh
        '.Save
    End With
    
    WasSuccessful = True
    
ProcExit:
    If Not Application.DisplayAlerts Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
    If Not Application.ScreenUpdating Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
    
    If WasSuccessful Then
        MsgBox "Worksheet '" & sName & "' exported.", vbInformation, ProcTitle
    Else
        MsgBox "Worksheet '" & sName & "' could not be exported." _
            & MsgString, vbCritical, ProcTitle
    End If
    
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    MsgString = vbLf & vbLf & "Procedure '" & ProcName _
        & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
        & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```

- If copying the complete worksheet is an option, replace the lines from `Dim srg As Range` through `dwb.Close` (19 lines) with the following:

```vb
sws.Copy
With ActiveWorkbook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
    .SaveAs Filename:=dFilePath, FileFormat:=xlCSV, Local:=True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    .Close
End With
```